# Apache: serving pre-compressed files & preventing double gzipping

Tags: linux, apache, localhost, gzip

I've been spending the last two days trying to find an effective way to serve pre-compressed gzip files in Apache on localhost.

I found the solution in [this](https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2016/01/20/serving-pre-compressed-files-with-apache-multiviews/#the-multiviews-method) post.

Just for a test, I created two CSS files, named *fabric.css.css* and *fabric.css.gz*, placed them in the same folder and edited the configuration file in */etc/apache2/sites-available* of my local website as follows:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/site2_test/public_html>
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +MultiViews
RemoveType .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gz
</Directory>
```

It seems to do the trick, as you can see here: [image]

**Content-location** points to the exact file and **Content-Type** is correct.

Now, my question is: how can you tell exactly whether your already-gzipped files are being gzipped **again** by Apache or not? If that's the case, what can you do to prevent that behavior?

Thank you! :-D

Comment: Take a look at the "Serving pre-compressed content" section of the mod_deflate documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I looked at that solution yesterday, but it seems not to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I placed that configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available and renamed my CSS test files in "fabric.css" and "fabric.gz". Despite all, there is nothing in the HTTP Headers that seems to suggest that Apache is using the pre-compressed fabric.gz instead of fabric.css. 

What's the "proof" that Apache is using the pre-compressed file instead of the un-compressed one?

Comment: I found the way to get the configuration in "Serving pre-compressed content" to work, too. It was enough to enable "mod_headers", add "RewriteEngine on" at the top of the configuration and pont the <link> tag in my HTML to the .css.gz version of the file.